# Difficulty installing hdf5r

Tags: r, macos, hdf5, bioconductor

I'm trying to install a package on Bioconductor called "Herper" and it requires "hdf5r" to be updated. I'm trying to update using compilation to get the most recent version of this package. Previously, I had issues with finding the hdf5 library but was able to rectify this by first installing hdf5 using homebrew and then using the following code to specify the location of the hdf5 library.

`install.packages("hdf5r", configure.args = "--with-hdf5=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/hdf5/1.12.2_2/bin/h5cc")`

Now I'm getting a new error where R is trying to find the object 'hdf5r.so'.

Here is where I believe things start going wrong:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/hdf5/1.12.2_2/lib/libhdf5_hl.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/hdf5/1.12.2_2/lib/libhdf5.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
installing to /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/00LOCK-hdf5r/00new/hdf5r/libs
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘hdf5r’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/00LOCK-hdf5r/00new/hdf5r/libs/hdf5r.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/00LOCK-hdf5r/00new/hdf5r/libs/hdf5r.so, 0x0006): symbol not found in flat namespace (_H5P_CLS_ATTRIBUTE_CREATE_ID_g)
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
```

I'm quite new to coding, so I believe the 00LOCK folders are temporary folders? Because I cannot find the path that R is searching for. Let me know if you guys have any solutions to this!

Cheers,
G

Comment: The `00LOCK` folders are set by R during an install so that it doesn't accidentally try to install again to the same location in the middle of an install. (You can be running more than one R instance at once.)  The errors on the first line look important:  you have an Intel Mac, but have ARM64 libs installed.

Comment: Why not accept the binary build of hdf5r that's available on CRAN?  It's for version 1.3.5.

Comment: Thanks for the info!! Good catch! I'm actually using an M1 Mac, but I'm running an intel version of R through Rosetta2 because Bionconductor does not support the M1 architecture. Is there a way to install intel hdf5 libraries...?

Comment: I have installed the version 1.3.5, but then when I try to install "Herper" it prompts to update hdf5r to 1.3.6. If I don't update then I get the error:

```Warning message:
package ‘Herper’ is not available for Bioconductor version '3.15'```

However it says on the Bioconductor webpage that Herper is released on 3.15

Comment: "Is there a way to install intel hdf5 libraries?"  I don't know.  Maybe if there's a way to run `brew` under Rosetta, or maybe there's some obscure option to run it that way.  I'm surprised BioC doesn't support the ARM Macs.  They've been out for a while...